# How often are MapQuest tiles updated with new OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapquest

When users make edits to OpenStreetMap, how long does it generally take for those edits to show up in the MapQuest tiles?  Is this on the order of hours, days, or months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MapQuest (Via OpenStreetMap Wiki)**

```
How often is the data updated?
The map data is updated approximately every 15 minutes
The search data is updated approximately every 5 minutes
The routing data is updated daily
```

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest#How_often_is_the_data_updated.3F

Comment: Thanks Mapperz... that link came up in my Google searchings this morning but wasn't working at that time.  Every 15 minutes is beyond my expectations, that's one heck of a churn for a global tileset.  Cheers

Comment: Mapquest only update 'changes' [updates,insert,deletions] not the entire dataset - it is more efficient to do it this that way. As for Map Tile updates it can be a bit harder (a lot more processing required).

Comment: I made some changes over 3 weeks ago, and have yet to see them reflected in the [MapQuest osm tiles](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/38.94048/-77.01167&layers=Q), though as you can see they are in all of the other renderings.  Any thoughts on that, @Mapperz?

Comment: data looks the same in osm and mapquest http://open.mapquest.com/#efcd6b5abf30370c63baa3ee is your browser caching the tiles? ctrl F5 to force referesh

Comment: just checked back here, didn't get any comment notification.  looks like the update process is busted right now: https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/frequency-updates-openstreetmap.  I'm talking about the mapquest tiles built from osm data.  you can see the building footprint difference in my previous link if you switch to any of the other layer renderings (standard, cycle map, etc).